# Clojure: creating a date-time object for the JDBC

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I created my PostgreSQL table with a column:

```
  updated_at timestamp(0) with time zone
```

I'm using [clojure.java-time](https://github.com/dm3/clojure.java-time) but I can't create a string (or should be an object?) to set the current date-time. I tried with:

```
 (time/format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss" (time/local-date-time))
```

and with that string I tried:

```
(db/update-answer! {:updated_at "2019-12-25 14:08", :id 102, :answer "Foo"}
```

but the JDBC tells me that the field "updated_at" doesn't have a valid type. As far as I understand the JDBC is still using the old java API for handle the dates and time zones and not the new in JDK 8. So, in summary I don't know how to create a string or an object valid for Postgresql time-stamp column using clojure.java-time.

Someone advises me about extending the JDBC protocol, I'm reading about it but for now I'm just looking for a way to create a valid object and finish this update.

**UPDATED**

After followed [this page](https://andersmurphy.com/2019/08/03/clojure-using-java-time-with-jdbc.html) I could give format to Instant with:

```
(ns zentaur.hiccup.helpers-view
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]
        [java-time :as jt])
 (:import [java.time ZoneId]))

(defn format-date [date]
 (log/info (str ">>> DATE >>>>> " date "und type >>> " (type date)))
 (jt/format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" (.atZone date  (ZoneId/systemDefault))))
```

Answer (score 3):

(Java syntax, not Clojure)

## tl;dr

**Use objects, not Strings.** Use *java.time* classes in Java, never the legacy date-time classes.

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(
    … , 
    OffsetDateTime.now()
)
```

Even better would be a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) to do this automatically.

> in summary I don't know how to create … an object valid for Postgresql time-stamp column using clojure.java-time.

Call **`OffsetDateTime.now()`** to get a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` object holding the current moment.

Use a database column of **type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`** rather than `TIMESTAMP` (short for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`).

## Moments

> set the current date-time

If you want to track moments, specific points on the timeline, you are using the wrong data type.

You are using `TIMESTAMP` which is short for `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. This type lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So this type cannot track moments. I suggest you avoid the short version of this type name in the future, to make your SQL clear. See [Postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

You should be defining your column as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Postgres handles this type by always saving the moment as seen in UTC. Any provided time zone or offset in the input is used to adjust to UTC. Likewise, when retrieved, your value is always in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Beware of middleware and tools that dynamically apply some time zone to the retrieved value. This clouds matters, creating the illusion that the value was stored in that time zone. The value was actually stored in UTC, always in UTC in Postgres.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

> but I can't create a string (or should be an object?) to set the current date-time.

Don’t.

You should be exchanging objects between Java and Postgres, rather than mere strings. This avoids the time-zone injection problem mentioned above.

As of JDBC 4.2, you can exchange modern *java.time* objects with the database. Never use the legacy types such as `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar`, `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp`, and so on. These classes were terribly flawed, designed by people who did not understand date-time handling. They were supplanted as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

Capture the current moment as an `OffsetDateTime`. Your JDBC driver might support `Instant` & `ZonedDateTime` but those types are optional, as seen in graphic table above. In contrast, JDBC requires support for `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

The explicit use of `ZoneOffset.UTC` in code above is not strictly required. If omitted, your JVM’s current default offset will be applied implicitly. Your JDBC driver and/or Postgres will adjust to UTC as discussed earlier above. My own preference for the sake of debugging/logging is to specify UTC so I can see the value as it will eventually be stored in the database.

And retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Default value

If you are simply recording the moment whenever a row is updated, no need to do that in your SQL. I suggest you write a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) to be called whenever a row in that table is updated. Then you are guaranteed the value will be written no matter the mechanism by which the row was updated. And less to worry about when writing your SQL statements.

Comment: Postgres also accepts `timestamptz` as shorthand for `timestamp with time zone`